# StartForeground () clears the notification after killing the application

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I am trying to make my `Service` running in foreground. Everything it's ok, but 
 **when I killed app, notification was cleared**.
One more note, it's not working on XIAOMI REDMI NOTE 4 with android 7.0.

Sample code :

```
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            notificationIntent,
            0
    );

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
    intent.setAction(STOP_SERVICE_ACTION);
    final PendingIntent stopIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    );

    final NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action(0, getString(R.string.stop), stopIntent);

    final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANEL_ID)
            .addAction(action)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.searching_in_surrounding))
            .build();

    startForeground(FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);  


 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null && STOP_SERVICE_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    if (isRunning) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: in onStartCommand you return START_STICKY  or START_NOT_STICKY ?which one you are using ?

Comment: I added onStartCommand method in sample code. Look at it now. @Basiljose

Comment: okay notification is cleared only in XIAOMI REDMI  phones right ?have you given the autostart permissioni for chinese ROM ?

Comment: I'm testing on Samsung S8, HTC One, Samsung Galaxy J7, Motorola GZ2. Only Xiaomi has cleared the notification. Autostart permission for Chinese ROM ? Really, I hear first time @Basiljose

Answer (score 0):

Please use this method to auto start the service in chinese rom devices , because these devices automatically `forcestop` the application when the are background or swiped off from recent task manager

```
public void auto_start_permission() {
    String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
    if (manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
        //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

for more reference [refer](https://medium.com/mindorks/enable-background-services-in-chinese-roms-32e73dfba1a6)

Comment: I turn on manually AutoStart for app earlier . This is not a solution to the problem.